# Images from URI source not showing in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have read all answers to similar questions and none of them address my issue. As you can see in my code snippet below and attached screen-shot, I have done everything advise for success but no luck.

1. I am retrieving photos from Flickr with https:// and valid api key (see code)
2. All the needed photos are successfully retrieved and stored in var imadeData (see screenshot)
3. FlatList used to list the items in 3 columns via photo id. Screenshot shows the 3 columns but no photos.

Photo.js

```
    const url = 'https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?&method=flickr.people.getPublicPhotos&api_key=' + API_KEY + '&user_id=46262470@N03&format=json&&per_page=20&nojsoncallback=1'; // MSU flickr

class Photos extends Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            imageData: [],
            isLoading: true,
            isError: false,
            text: '',
            columns: 3,
            key: 1,
        };
    }

getImageData=() => {

        return fetch( url )

            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {

                this.setState({
                    isLoading: false,
                    imageData: responseJson.photos.photo
                });
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
            });
    };


    componentDidMount() {

        this.getImageData();

    }
<FlatList
                numColumns={ columns }

                data = { imageData }
                // extraData={this.state}
                renderItem={ ( { item, index } ) => {

                    return <ImageList itemWidth={ (ITEM_WIDTH - (10 * columns)) / columns }
                                     photoId={ {uri: item.id } } />

                }}
                keyExtractor={
                    (item, index ) => {
                        return `${item.id + index}`
                        // return { index }
                    }
                }
                // refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
                // onRefresh={this.handleRefresh}
            />
```

ImageList.js

```
render () {

        const {itemWidth, photoId, onPressItem } = this.props;

        return (
            <Card>

                <TouchableWithoutFeedback

                    onPress = {() => onPressItem && onPressItem(this.props.photoId)}
                    onPressIn = {() => this.animateIn()}
                    onPressOut ={ () => this.animateOut()} >

                    <Animated.View style={{
                        margin:5,
                        // backfaceVisibility: 'hidden',
                        transform: [
                            {
                                scale: 1
                            },{
                            rotateY: this.state.animateItem.interpolate({
                                inputRange: [0,1],
                                outputRange: ['180deg','0deg']
                            })
                            }
                        ]
                    }}>
                        <Image style={{width: itemWidth, height: 200 }} source={{ photoId }} />
                    </Animated.View>
                </TouchableWithoutFeedback>

            </Card>

        );


    }
```

[Chrome console log with no errors and correct data retrieved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9PFp.png)

[iOS simulator screen showing grid view with no photos[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h50Vt.png)

Edits:

Per the pointer from the last response, I have recreated the photoId as a new variable photoURL that has the full url instead of just the photo id.  I use the following: const  photoURL = 'https://farm' + item.farm + '.static.flickr.com/' + item.server + '/' + item.id + '_' + item.secret + '_c.jpg';

```
 const  photoURL = 'https://farm' + item.farm + '.static.flickr.com/' + item.server + '/' + item.id + '_' + item.secret + '_c.jpg';

                    return <ImageList itemWidth={ (ITEM_WIDTH - (10 * columns)) / columns }
                                     image={ {uri: photoURL } } />
```

I also verified that the correct photos are being returned as param to the image src uri by pasting each coded photo into the browser.

But images are still not being displayed in my app screen with this correction.  Please help me as I am at my whims end.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The screen is blank because of 2 oversights on my part.

1. The data prop supplied to FlatList was not its new state (i.e. stating data = { imageData } was incorrect. Corrected this to: data = {this.state.imageData }
2. In passing data to the ImageList component, I forgot to pass the new data array by including prop data = { item }.  I was wrongly focussed on constructing a uri prop instead.  This is an advice against naming components and variables similar to RN library elements. Both variables I used made me think I was composing an image statement.

App is now working properly : fetching AD displaying the images as a grid of 3 columns or as any columns as one desires.

Another advice is to ensure you include a return before the component being called in the renderItem section of FlatList.

Answer (score 4):

Are you pictures stored locally ? If not, your Image component does not have the right `source` prop. If you want to use an uri, it should look like this :

```
<Image style={{width: itemWidth, height: 200 }} source={{ uri: photoId }} />
```

and `photoId`is an url.

Take a look at [this documention](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html)

Comment: the photoId is passed as a prop from the photo.js where it is retrieved via a JSON response from Flickr.  It is a valid source with data returned.  Please see the code snippets.  If you see something I need to fix in tpassing the dat between components (photo.js and imageList.js) or otherwise please advise.  Thx for your response.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is re rendering not occurs as the url changes(initially it is undefined).

Uncomment extraData value so that `flatList` know that data is changed and re rendering occurs then images will be shown.

```
<FlatList
                numColumns={ columns }

                data = { imageData }
                extraData={this.state}
                renderItem={ ( { item, index } ) => {

                    return <ImageList itemWidth={ (ITEM_WIDTH - (10 * columns)) / columns }
                                     photoId={ {uri: item.id } } />

                }}
                keyExtractor={
                    (item, index ) => {
                        return `${item.id + index}`
                        // return { index }
                    }
                }
            />
```